# Can I keep a websocket connection in background and terminated state on android?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-process

I'm working on an android application that uses  websockets. The app has to receive notifications when in background or terminated state. So there must be a connection with the server always even if the app in not running. Just like what whatsapp do. The question is ,**is  it ok to always keep a network connection in background according to the android regulations**. Android also enforces developers to indicate to the user that the app is running in background , for all android sdk's greater than sdk 26. But if I look at other apps such as whatsapp , telegram , tiktok they don't indicate to the users ( but we do know their apps run in background or terminated state). How are they achieving this without violating the android regulations.

I've also tried Firebase Cloud Messaging but  the problem is I can't make use of the websocket connection , thus less control over the functionalities.

Comment: "but we do know their apps run in background or terminated state" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly? If it is because they react to things like incoming messages, they use Firebase Cloud Messaging (or equivalents in non-Play ecosystems).